# When does $\lfloor{np}\rfloor \le np \le \lfloor{np}\rfloor+1$ not hold?

Tags: inequality

I am asking myself if one can find some natural number $n$ and a $0<p<1$ such that 
$$\lfloor{np}\rfloor \le np \le \lfloor{np}\rfloor+1$$ does NOT hold?

Comment: Never.  How could it not hold?

Comment: Even $np<[np]+1$ holds.

Comment: However $\lfloor np \rfloor \le np \le \lfloor np + 1\rfloor$ will often fail.  Is *that* what you were asking.

Comment: The definition of $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is $\lfloor x \rfloor \le x$, $\lfloor x \rfloor\in \mathbb Z$ and $\lfloor x \rfloor +1 > x$.

Comment: @fleabood how it could fail? When the identity $\lfloor x \rfloor+1=\lfloor x +1\rfloor$ fails?

Comment: Even if it were possible that $\lfloor x \rfloor + 1= \lfloor x + 1\rfloor$ failed, that in no way would imply $x < \lfloor x\rfloor $ or that $\lfloor x \rfloor + 1< x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every possible real $x$, it is true that $\lfloor x\rfloor \le x <\lfloor x\rfloor +1$

So for every possible real $x$, it is true that $\lfloor x\rfloor \le x \le\lfloor x\rfloor+ 1$ (although the second inequality *never* holds).

And it doesn't matter what the gahoozits $n$ or $p$ is, it will always be true than

$\lfloor np \rfloor \le np \le\lfloor np\rfloor+ 1$.

It's never not true.